# Copy Map[String,List[MyObject]] to Copy Map[String,List[String]] scala

Tags: scala

Is there a fancy way in scala to copy a map from a value type to another value type?

```
Input: Map[String, ListBuffer[MyCustomObject]]
output: Map[String, ListBuffer[String]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: `myMap.mapValues(_.map(_.toString))`

Comment: Thanks @Jean-PhilippePellet

Comment: Note that `mapValues` wraps the original map without copying it. The function `_.map(_.toString)` is applied every time you get a value out of the resulting map. ( http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.Map@mapValues[C](f:B=>C):scala.collection.Map[A,C] )

Answer (score 1):

While `.mapValues` only creates a view of the original collection, using `.map` gives you an entirely independent new collection.

```
input.map { case (key, value) => (key, value.map(_.toString)) }
```